# Editing Xml file in C# (WP8)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, windows-phone-8

I am trying to edit a local xml file in C# for my Windows Phone 8 app.
On the web, I found countless examples using `XmlDocument` using methods like `AppendChild`.
In Windows Phone 8, `XmlDocument` has been replaced by `XDocument` and `AppendChild` disappeared.
I tried the code below but get some error on `protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)`:
The error can be seen here: http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz38/JelleK1996/cerror1_zpsb6aa5398.png

Can anyone help me out?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using XmlLocalEdit1.Resources;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XmlLocalEdit1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
                xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                xws.Indent = true;

                using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws))
                {
                    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Resources/bar.xml");
                    XElement xmlTree = new XElement("data",
                        new XElement("cocktail",
                            new XElement("name", "Dreamsicle"),
                            new XElement("id", 1)
                        )
                    );
                    xdoc.Add(xmlTree);
                    xdoc.Save(xw);
                }

                //xdoc.Add(xmlTree);
                //xdoc.Save("Resources/bar.xml", SaveOptions.None);

            }
            catch (Exception myExc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myExc.Message);
            }
        }

        /*private static XElement CreateCocktail(XDocument xmlDoc,
                                                string name,
                                                int id)
        {
            var xmlCocktail = xmlDoc
        }*/
    }
}
```

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <cocktail>
    <name>43 Hedonism</name>
    <id>14</id>
  </cocktail>
  <cocktail>
    <name>B-52</name>
    <id>4</id>
  </cocktail>
</data>
```

Comment: `I tried the code below but get some error on protected override void` - What is `some error`?

Comment: Added a link to the error: http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz38/JelleK1996/cerror1_zpsb6aa5398.png

Comment: Where is your xml file located? It seems, like it's in the Resources, and I'm not sure, that you can edit a file there in windows-phone. If you want to edit this file, you should copy it to isolated storage and then work with that copy.

Comment: Maybe at that breakpoint you move the mouse over myExc and provide us the values for `Message` and `StackTrace`?

Comment: `This operation would create an incorrectly structured document`. Sorry I didn't post this before but I'm new to C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, here a sample for you.

I strongly recommend you to use IsolatedStorage instead of editing the file in resources.

```
            // copy the xml file to isolated storage
            using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!file.FileExists("bar.xml"))
                {
                    StreamResourceInfo sr_en = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources\\bar.xml", UriKind.Relative));
                    using (BinaryReader br_en = new BinaryReader(sr_en.Stream))
                    {
                        byte[] data = br_en.ReadBytes((int)sr_en.Stream.Length);
                        //Write the file.
                        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(file.CreateFile("bar.xml")))
                        {
                            bw.Write(data);
                            bw.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                // work with file at isolatedstorage
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("bar.xml", FileMode.Open, file))
                {
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);

                    // add new node to data section
                    doc.Descendants("data").FirstOrDefault().Add(
                        new XElement("cocktail",
                            new XElement("name", "Dreamsicle"),
                            new XElement("id", 1)
                        )
                    );
                    // prevent xml file from doubling nodes
                    if (stream.CanSeek)
                        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    doc.Save(stream);
                }
            }
```

Comment: "Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 11, position 10." Is it possible that a Byte Order Mark was added when writing the xml file to the IsolatedStorage? And if so, how can I easily delete it in this code?

Comment: @JelleKerkstra, to see the changed file, you should use isolated storage explorer extension for Visual Studio(there are several of them, all free). However, the IS explorer is created to work with real phone device (the given screenshot shows, that you're using an emulator), so you may face some problems. The error, you've received is most likely the extra whitespace or commentary before "<?xml" tag. When do you get this error? You can add watch to doc object and check, if it has correct format before and after editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will add another `<data>` element to the xml file, resulting an xml with multiple root elements which is not a valid xml format. I guess you want to add another `<cocktail>` element to existing `<data>` element instead. If this is the case, you can try this way :

```
.......
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Resources/bar.xml");
XElement xmlTree = new XElement("cocktail",
        new XElement("name", "Dreamsicle"),
        new XElement("id", 1)
    );
//add new <cocktail> to existing root, which is <data> element
xdoc.Root.Add(xmlTree);
xdoc.Save(xw);
.......
```